# Switch Between Two Cells in Jupyterlab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

Is it possible to switch between the current cell and another specific cell in JupyterLab?

I want to show my students the result in, for example, cell [20], but I am currently in cell [100], and scrolling up to cell 20 can be cumbersome. I am looking for a more convenient way to switch between these two cells easily.

I just scroll up and down between these two cells.

Comment: Surprisingly, looks like there is no such command: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/commands.html. I'm not a jupyterlab user, but navigation inside the current file looks like "obviously needed" feature - consider raising this feature request with maintainers if nobody gives a "yes, you can" answer here. They have "go to line" for CSV mode or "file editor", but apparently it's not the same as running notebook.

Comment: There seems to be a workaround: creating a hyperlink to a target markdown cell. See this [similar unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54839109/jump-to-a-particular-code-cell-from-a-code-cell-i-e-programmatically-jupyter).